Why is my Drools application using a large amount of memory for JoinNodeLeftTuple objects, and how can I optimize my rules?
I'm working on a Drools-based application, and I've been experiencing high memory usage, particularly due to a large number of JoinNodeLeftTuple objects in the heap. This seems to scale with the number of events I'm looking for. For example, when I'm looking for 5,000 events, it results in about 2.5 million JoinNodeLeftTuple objects, and when I increase the search to 10,000 events, the number of JoinNodeLeftTuple objects jumps to 31 million.
This is one of my rules:
rule "Attack 50113 - Level 5 - ID 4"
when
    $scenario: Scenario(sid == 50113, rid == 3)
    $prevLevel: Attack() from $scenario.lastAttack
    Number(this >= 4000) from accumulate(
              $a : RequestEvent(sourceIp == $scenario.getAttack(0).sourceIp, pluginId == 4003, pluginSid == 1, this after[1ms, 86400s] $prevLevel),
              count($a)
    )

    $clock: PseudoClockScheduler()
then
    ...
end

Previously, I formed an arraylist out of these accumulated RequestEvents and stored them in the next Attack object I created. I removed them and it didn't seem to have any effects on garbage collection.
Now, I'm dumping the heap and analyzing it using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer. Here's the histogram resulted from using the aforementioned rule:
heap dump histogram
My questions are:

Is the use of accumulate with a time window in the rule likely to be the cause of the high memory usage associated with JoinNodeLeftTuple objects?
Are there alternative ways to count events that would be more memory-efficient, possibly avoiding the accumulation of so many JoinNodeLeftTuple objects?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
Here's a quick example of it with 5000 logs total, it should result in 2.5 million JoinNodeLeftTuple objects which is what I'm trying to figure out the reason for.
see github repository
I understand that these tuple objects have a reference to a sink and from what I've seen in Memory Analyzer, their sinks are the accumulate nodes. So, as a trivial answer to my first question, Yes! Accumulate nodes are responsible for these tuples.

could you please share minimal example to run and reproduce the issue?

@Mike I apologize for the late response. I've uploaded a minimal example and updated the main post adding the link.

hi @yuriz, I didn't have time to look at it before, and yesterday when I tried to download, file is no longer available. Could you please upload it again to file share or even (more convenient and safer) to github.

hi @Mike. I'm sorry the link was expired. I've uploaded the files to github and edited the original post. Thank you.

Interesting catch...
I've reproduced the issue.
First of all, could you please remove mixing drools api 6 and core 8 libraries version by for removing api 6 from dependencies.
Class not found issue could be then fixed by for fixing import
import org.kie.api.time.SessionClock;
import org.drools.core.time.SessionPseudoClock;
import org.drools.core.time.impl.PseudoClockScheduler;

I've not solved the issue yet (is it an issue?).
if ignoring extremal count of objects, do you experience OOM errors?
If so, could you update your event files with mode data to experience it?
Could you try adding System.gc() after some amount of data inserted, does it relax? (I mean count of object is not yet an issue, these could be volatile objects)
Though I got to some extent, but it is hard to reverse engineer the logic. Could you please explain a bit the logic of 'we've got one final scenario.' rule?

The drools api 6 dependency is removed now.
At first I thought it is an issue but I guess it is how accumulate works to avoid looking over all of the facts again and again, by storing these tuples; And as more events come in, more scenarios are created and those also store more tuples and ... this leads to an exponentially growing heap.
So, when there are fewer events OOM does not happen but I really don't want that.
I've also added another event which signals System.gc and insert one such signal every 100 events. It really did not have much of an impact.

For the "we've got one final scenario." there's not much of a logic behind it; It is just there to tell me whether the final level is achieved or not. I know there are much cleaner ways to test for that. My rules require 1, 5, 100, 1000 and 4000 logs to reach the final level and hence the 5106 logs stored in logs.csv.
A bit more on System.gc(), it actually made an small difference, reducing the JoinNodeLeftTuple objects in the heap from 2,625,000 to 2,575,000 and memory usage by 5MB. Thank you @Mike for your answers. Let me know if I misunderstood your words.

My question now is that how can I replace the accumulate logic with another drools feature that doesn't require actually storing those tuples? I've tried using counters to count the objects but that approach, despite using little memory, is too slow.
